# sqlalchemy scalar subquery conversion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

The query I want to convert looks like this:

```sql
    SELECT
        sum(CASE
                WHEN (countryCd3 = (
                    SELECT
                        countryCd3 as id2
                    FROM myTable
                    where a.countryCd3 = id2
                    GROUP BY countryCd3
                    HAVING count(countryCd3) > 1) AND countryCd3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) AS unexpected_count
    FROM myTable as a;
```

This is in Teradata and it works. The issue I have is converting this to sqlalchemy, especially passing there where line with the appropriate aliases.

What I have tried so far:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
table_outer = sa.table('myTable', sa.column('countryCd3'))
table_inner = sa.table('myTable', sa.column('countryCd3'))

inner_query = (sa.select([sa.column(column)])
               .where(table_outer.c.id == table_inner.c.id)
               .select_from(table_inner)
               .group_by(sa.column(column))
               .having(sa.func.count(sa.column(column)) > 1))

print(inner_query)
```

Output:

```
SELECT countryCd3 
FROM "myTable", "myTable" 
WHERE "myTable".countryCd3 = "myTable".countryCd3 GROUP BY countryCd3 
HAVING count(countryCd3) > :count_1
```

Haven't tried to construct the outer query given this issue currently.

Comment: Just as in native SQL, you need to assign a different ALIAS to each instance of myTable, e.g. `table_outer = sa.table('myTable', sa.column('countryCd3')).alias('a')`

Comment: Thanks! When I tried that, the resulting value of the inner_query becomes: ```sql SELECT id  FROM "myTable" AS a, "myTable"  WHERE a.countryCd3 = "myTable".countryCd3 GROUP BY countryCd3  HAVING count(countryCd3) > :count_1```.  The `FROM` clause in the inner query adds both tables whereas we would just want to refer to `myTable` once in the inner query.

Comment: Your inner query is "correlated";  it refers to the outer table (a.countryCd3) so you really can't construct the inner query alone.

Comment: And you really should alias references for both instances and qualify all column references with the appropriate alias  in the Teradata SQL version as well as in sqlalchemy - rather than one aliased and one not.